# Swift - Is There A "Dictionary With Duplicate Keys" Workaround?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, alamofire

Currently I am working with alamofire to send post requests to a certain site. In the paramaters of the post request, there is a duplicate key entry that is required to send the post request, but when I am making the dictionary and enter both keys as string literals, I receive the nasty "Duplicate Keys in dictionary" error which does not allow me to use the parameters I need to use. For example:

```
let post_data = [
    "test": "0",
    "test": "1"
]

Alamofire.request("https://testsite.com/testpost", method: .post, parameters: post_data).responseString { (data) in
    print(data)
  }
```

When writing this, the error appears with the post_data dictionary and does not allow me to run my code. I was wondering if there were any workarounds to this error. I have searched through multiple stack overflow questions, but most of them talk about removing duplicate keys instead of working around them. Thanks!

Comment: The web site's API is broken.  The value for `test` should be an array.  If you can't change it then you are going to have to manually construct your POST data string.

Comment: @Paulw11 Awesome! Thanks for such a quick response! Really appreciate the answer!

Answer (score 5):

Try using a `DictionaryLiteral`:

```
let a: DictionaryLiteral = [
    "a": 0,
    "a": 1,
]

print(a) // DictionaryLiteral<String, Int>(_elements: [("a", 0), ("a", 1)])
```

Comment: Note: `DictionaryLiteral` does not conform to `Encodable`, so it may not work for your use-case.

Comment: It did fix the issue but as you stated, because it does not conform to Encodable, it will not work with Alamofire. Nevertheless, I appreciate your answer!